# Instagram API picture URL (2018)

Tags: image, url, instagram, instagram-api, social-networking

how do I get a larger resolution from a picture URL like this:

```
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/ca89afc73ba2b787ed1621db3f534ea6/5C150A5B/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14719833_310540259320655_1605122788543168512_a.jpg
```

to this (or larger resolution)

```
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/c69e38de6818d8d513663a87e2e6f535/5C2924AB/t51.2885-19/s320x320/14719833_310540259320655_1605122788543168512_a.jpg
```

there is a way to get the media ID from the first URL and then find the large resolution URL?

I have searched and saw that if you remove this part "s150x150" from the URL it's will work but it's not.

Comment: If you not only have the low resolution profile pic url, but also have the user's id (which can be easily found out if you have the username), you can use the following JSON query to get the hd profile pic url: 
     `curl -s https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USERID/info/ | jq -r .user.hd_profile_pic_url_info.url`